question for AccessibilityNodeInfo.CollectionInfo
I failed to implement a list imformation using CollectionInfo and CollectionItemInfo.
I've success to compile, and application is also launched. I expected TallkBack to read the total number of list items and the current item index.
But, TalkBack doesn't read the number of listitems and a current item index when I touch any tab item.
I don't know why it doesn't work. What else do I need to use CollectionInfo and CollectionItemInfo?
the below code is my kotlin code implementing tab controls.
I copied usages of CollectionInfo and CollectionItemInfo in TabLayout.java. My code's the almost same with "TabLayout.java".
LinearLayout.accessibilityDelegate = object: AccessibilityDelegate() {
    override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(
        host: View,
        info: AccessibilityNodeInfo
    ){
        if(count != null) {
            infoCompat.setCollectionInfo(
                CollectionInfoCompat.obtain(
                    1,
                    count,
                    false,
                    CollectionInfo.SELECTION_MODE_SINGLE
                )
            )
        }
    }
}

// Item AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat
val tabTexts:List<TextView> = listOf(R.id.hw_text,R.id.hw_text_ko,R.id.hw_text_ja,R.id.hw_text_de).map { findViewById(it) }

tabTexts.forEachIndexed{ index, tab ->
    tab.accessibilityDelegate = object: AccessibilityDelegate() {
        override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(
            host: View,
            info: AccessibilityNodeInfo
        ){        
            infoCompat.setCollectionItemInfo(CollectionItemInfoCompat.obtain(
                    0,
                    1,
                    index,
                    1,
                    false,
                    selected == true
                )
            )
        }
    }
}


And Below is the custom tab control layout xml.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/tablist">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World"
            android:id="@+id/hw_text"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10sp"
            android:padding="4sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="안녕 세계"
            android:id="@+id/hw_text_ko"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10sp"
            android:padding="4sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="こんにちは、世界"
            android:id="@+id/hw_text_ja"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10sp"
            android:padding="4sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hallo Welt"
            android:id="@+id/hw_text_de"
            android:padding="4sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


try replacing all the Compat items with regular ones.
e.g. CollectionInfoCompat -> CollectionInfo
